# In Lodash library of JavaScript, why it swap start number with end number if the start number is greather than end number?

Tags: javascript, lodash, libraries

Lodash's `inRange(number, startNumber, endNumber);`

Can't understand why it swaps `startNumber` with `endNumber`, if `startNumber` is greater than `endNumber`?
I read the documentation but still don't understand why.

Comment: Because sometimes you get two values without knowing which is start and which is end, so it's just a useful feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's syntactic sugaring. The functionality is to check whether a number is between two other numbers (`start` and `end`), regardless of which one of them is greater than the other.